# android - Butterknife bind inside custom view to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, butterknife

I have a fragment which holds a custom view.

in the fragment I do the `ButterKnife.bind` like this:

```
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, root);
```

And I manage to bind the views.

Now, the fragment holds a custom view I created.
In the `MenuToggleButton` custom view I want to bind another view, and operate with it.

The problem I am having is, I don't know how to access the root view of the fragment from inside the custom view (which is in the fragment).

```
public MenuToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        final Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        ButterKnife.bind(this, // need to get the fragment root view somehow);
    }
```

How can I get the fragment root view on order to bind it like I did in the fragment?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921876/using-butterknife-library-with-2-different-views-in-1-fragment) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ViewHolder in your custom view to be able to use ButterKnife there.  Or you can get views traditional way by findViewById.
So with ButterKnife your custom view would be something like this:

```
class MenuToggleButton{
    public MenuToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        View v = inflate(context, R.layout.menu_toggle_button, this);
        (new ViewHolder(v)).init();
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        @BindView(R.id.some_view)
        SomeView someView;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }

        init() {
            someView.doSomething();
        }

    }
```

}